# Probability question related to gambling and statistics

Tags: statistics, solution-verification

I am given the following problem, can someone take a look at my solution and provide feedback?

Question:

> Consider the following variant on a gambling game. Each time you play, if you gamble $s$ units of wealth and win, then your stake is returned to you *together* with winnings of $ks$. If you lose you forfeit your stake. Let the robability of winning each time you play be $p$.
>
> Suppose you stake a proportion $\alpha$ of your current wealth on each gamble. Using the weak law of large numbers describe how your wealth will behave after many gambles and compute the optimal choice of $\alpha$ when $k = 2$ and $p = \frac{2}{3}$.

---

**Solution:** WLOG suppose that we start with $1$ unit of wealth, $n$ gambling games were played and we ended with $W$ units of wealth. Let the random variable $X_i$ be the ratio $\frac{\text{wealth after}\ i\text{th gamble}}{\text{wealth before}\ i\text{th gamble}}$. Then,

$$\mathbb{P}(X_i = 1 + k\alpha) = p \quad\text{and}\quad \mathbb{P}(X_i = 1 - \alpha) = 1 - p$$

Also, we have

$$W = X_1 X_2 \cdots X_n = \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i\right)$$

Now, define the new variables $Y_i = \frac{\log X_i - \log(1 - \alpha)}{\log(1 + k\alpha) - \log(1 - \alpha)}$. Then,

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_i = 1) = p \quad\text{and}\quad \mathbb{P}(Y_i = 0) = 1 - p$$

Also, rearranging gives that $\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i = \left(\log(1 + k\alpha) - \log(1 - \alpha)\right)\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i + n\log(1 - \alpha)$. Now, we know that $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \sim B(n, p)$. Thus, by the Weak Law of Large Numbers, for all $\epsilon > 0$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(\Big|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}{n} - p\Big| < \epsilon\right) = 1$$

That is, after large number of trials, $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\sim np$, and

$$W = \exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i\right) \sim \exp(n(p\log(1 + k\alpha) + (1 - p)\log(1 - \alpha)))$$

Finally, to maximise the amount of wealth $W$, we maximise

$$\exp(p\log(1 + k\alpha) + (1 - p)\log(1 - \alpha)) = (1 + k\alpha)^p (1 - \alpha)^{1 - p}$$

For $k = 2$ and $p = \frac{2}{3}$, we shall maximise $(1 + 2\alpha)^{\frac{2}{3}} (1 - \alpha)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Equivalently, we maximise $(1 + 2\alpha)^2 (1 - \alpha) = -4\alpha^3 + 3\alpha + 1$, which achieves its maximum at $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$.

---

In particular, is there any easier way to see the linear map from $X_i$ to $Y_i$ from the problem?

Comment: You have come up with the [Kelly criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_criterion) solution.  It is a very good solution, even though it does not maximise expected wealth (betting a higher proportion each time would increase the expectation but increase the risk more); instead it maximises $\mathbb E[\log(\text{wealth})]$

Comment: @Henry Can you give a more detailed explanation for how my solution does not maximise expected wealth? e.g. For $n = 2$, how can I do better?

Comment: With $n=2$ rounds, following your $\alpha=\frac12$ strategy, there is a probability $\frac49$ you win twice and end up with $4$, probability $\frac49$ you win once and lose once and end up with $1$ and  probability $\frac19$ you lose twice and end up with $\frac14$, so an expected outcome of $\frac94=2.25$.  With an $\alpha=1$ strategy, there is a probability $\frac49$ you win twice and end up with $9$, and a probability $\frac59$ you lose all your money and end up with $0$, so an expected outcome of $4$, which is higher but more risky.

Comment: The problem with an $\alpha=1$ strategy is that for large $n$ you are very likely to end up bankrupt.  Hence an alternative strategy of maximising $\mathbb E[\log(\text{wealth})]$ or maximising the median of the distribution of final wealth, or something else.

Comment: @Henry I see, thank you, and thanks for the reading on Kelly's Criterion as well.